# BeginForm dont sent model to Controller method POST why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, post, model-view-controller

I have problem i dont now how to fix it.

I have ViewModel

```
public class CartOrderViewModel
{
    public Cart Carts;
    public Order Orders;
    public string name;
}
```

in CartController method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
 CartOrderViewModel vm = new CartOrderViewModel
            {
                Carts = _cart,
                Orders = new Order() { User = applicationUser },
            };
return View(vm);
}
```

**View Index** from CartController

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Cart", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name)

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

and in my method Test in CartController i dont see ViewModel CartOrderViewModel

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test(CartOrderViewModel test)
{
      string komentarz = test.name;
      return View();
}
```

Model: test in null.
Please help me. Thx a lot

How to send form from Index View from CartController my ViewModel CartOrderViewModel
example Model.Order.name ??

Why my name from CartOrderViewModel dont sent to method Test from index View ?

printscreen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFjeq.jpg)

Comment: ASP.NET binds to **properties**, not fields. Change all of the `public` fields in `class CartOrderViewModel` to be mutable properties with `{ get; set; }`.

Comment: Omg thx a lot. I spend two day in this problem. Thx you. This is it. 
Its post is close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why my name from CartOrderViewModel dont sent to method Test from index View ?

ASP.NET binds to properties, not fields. Change all of the public fields in `class CartOrderViewModel` to be mutable properties with `{ get; set; }`.

Like so:

```
public class CartOrderViewModel
{
    public Cart?   Carts  { get; set; }
    public Order?  Orders { get; set; }
    public String? Name   { get; set; }
}
```

Don't forget to add validation attributes, such as `[Required]`, as per your project's needs.